# Cancel componentUnmount when navigating away

Tags: reactjs

I would like to give a user notification if they have started an application and are navigating away without saving. Once they click on another tab, the componentWillUnmount function will fire, is there anyway I can cancel it in case a user decides to stay on the same form?

Comment: Are you using react router? If so, there is a way to hook into a transition, but I need to know more. A quick solution off the top of my head would be to listen to a click on these other "tab" components you mention and trigger an alert before navigating.

Comment: yes i'm using react router. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using React Router, see [Confirming Navigation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md).